# Large number of channels in a hyperledger fabric network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

Is there a limit on number of channels in a Hyperledger Fabric network?
What are the implications of larger number of channels?

Thanks,
Naveen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an [upper bound](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/blob/release-1.4/sampleconfig/configtx.yaml#L279) that you can define for the ordering service:

> ```
> # Max Channels is the maximum number of channels to allow on the ordering
> # network. When set to 0, this implies no maximum number of channels. MaxChannels: 0
> ```

In the peer, every channel logic is maintained by its own goroutines and data structures.
I'm pretty confident that unless for very extreme use cases, you shouldn't be too worried about the number of channels a peer has joined to.

Comment: Link is dead :(

Comment: Thanks, I edited it the answer, now it's not dead anymore.